# C# - Optional Async for Interface

Tags: c#, asynchronous, interface

I have two Interfaces:

```
interface ICommandAsync : ICommand
{
    new Task Run(params string[] args);
}
```

and

```
interface ICommand
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Desc { get; }
    void Run(params string[] args);
}
```

> 'CommandWeather' does not implement interface member 'ICommand.Run(params string[])'. 'CommandWeather.Run(params string[])' cannot implement 'ICommand.Run(params string[])' because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'.

Here is `CommandWeather`, or the offending class:

```
class CommandWeather : ICommandAsync
{
    public async Task Run(params string[] args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

My question is this: How can I make an interface that is optionally async? I need the methods to have the same name since they will both be called with `Run()`, and only a few implementations of `ICommand` or `ICommandAsync` actually need to use `async`. This means that I get green lines for having a synchronous async method.

Comment: Usually, `async` method has suffix Async, in your case RunAsync... Or use explicit interface implementation...

Comment: @Johnny The problem with that is that I the command like this: `item.Key.Run(cmdTxt.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray());` because I parse all the commands from a yml file and then search for the appropriate file with that name. Would it be possible to have it call `RunAsync()` for commands that implement that?

Comment: @Johnny to clarify, `cmdTxt` is the User's input for a command, `item` is the `<ICommand, List<String>>` entry of the command currently looped (I loop through all of the commands to find the one with the right name. The List is for all aliases).

Comment: maybe you could use explicit interface and try to cast it to `ICommandAsync` if it fails call the sync one otherwise call the async one...

Comment: @Johnny sounds good ;) thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446876/how-to-create-and-implement-interfaces-for-operations-that-are-only-sometimes-as/55447033#55447033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement at least one of them explicitly.

```
class CommandWeather : ICommandAsync
{
    public async Task Run(params string[] args)
    {
        //...
    }

    // Explicitly implement ICommand.Run
    void ICommand.Run(params string[] args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This is how `IEnumerator.Current` has to be implemented since `IEnumerator<T>.Current` is declared with `new` and is of type `T` rather than `object`.

@Johnny makes a good point, though, that async methods usually have the `Async` suffix.  That would also solve the problem.